# How to subset identical rows from dataframe by condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

From this dataframe I want to subset rows which have the identical "model", "Country" and "year" values but different "factor"

```
model <- c("A","B","C","A","A","C","B","A")
country <- c("Italy","Germany","Norway","Italy","France","Germany","Norway","Italy")
year <- c(2016,2016,2016,2016,2015,2015,2015,2015)
value <-  c(14,24,11,34,73,11,33,22)
factor <- c("NEW","OLD","OLD","OLD","OLD","OLD","NEW","NEW")

df <- data.frame(model,country,year,value, factor)

  model country year value factor
1     A   Italy 2016    14    NEW
2     B Germany 2016    24    OLD
3     C  Norway 2016    11    OLD
4     A   Italy 2016    34    OLD
5     A  France 2015    73    OLD
6     C Germany 2015    11    OLD
7     B  Norway 2015    33    NEW
8     A   Italy 2015    22    NEW
```

Expected output:

```
1     A   Italy 2016    22    NEW
4     A   Italy 2016    34    OLD
```

Comment: Should the output not be 14 instead of 22 for row 1?

Comment: might I know why you rolled back the edit removing tags? ```loops```  ```for-loop``` ```dplyr``` ```tidyverse``` are all not named in your question or part of your code.  To quote form the help centre: >"A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question. Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer by sorting questions into specific, well-defined categories."

Answer (score 3):

What you could do is create a column which tells the number of duplicated based on the groups (model, country and year) and then `filter` like this:

```r
model <- c("A","B","C","A","A","C","B","A")
country <- c("Italy","Germany","Norway","Italy","France","Germany","Norway","Italy")
year <- c(2016,2016,2016,2016,2015,2015,2015,2015)
value <-  c(14,24,11,34,73,11,33,22)
factor <- c("NEW","OLD","OLD","OLD","OLD","OLD","NEW","NEW")

df <- data.frame(model,country,year,value, factor)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(model, country, year) %>% 
  mutate(number_dups = n()) %>% 
  filter(number_dups > 1) %>%
  select(-number_dups) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   model country  year value factor
#>   <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#> 1 A     Italy    2016    14 NEW   
#> 2 A     Italy    2016    34 OLD
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Please note:** I assume that the expected output should be 14 instead of 22.

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you can use `subset` + `ave`

```
> subset(df, ave(seq_along(year), model, country, year, FUN = length) > 1)
  model country year value factor
1     A   Italy 2016    14    NEW
4     A   Italy 2016    34    OLD
```

---

Or, try `Filter` + `split`

```
> Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, split(df, ~ model + country + year))
$A.Italy.2016
  model country year value factor
1     A   Italy 2016    14    NEW
4     A   Italy 2016    34    OLD
```

or

```
> do.call(rbind, unname(Filter(function(x) nrow(x) > 1, split(df, ~ model + country + year))))
  model country year value factor
1     A   Italy 2016    14    NEW
4     A   Italy 2016    34    OLD
```

Answer (score 2):

You can group by `model`, `country`, and `year`, then use `filter` to keep rows that have duplicated values for `model`, `country`, and `year`. Then, to ensure that there are different factor values, we use `n_distinct` to make sure there are at least 2 distinct values in `factor` (i.e., the group must have `NEW` and `OLD`).

```
library(dplyr)
    
df %>%
  group_by(model, country, year) %>%
  filter(n() > 1 & n_distinct(factor) > 1)
```

**Output**

```
  model country  year value factor
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 A     Italy    2016    14 NEW   
2 A     Italy    2016    34 OLD
```

***Additional Example**: Multiple Factors in Each Group*

If you only want to keep 1 row of different factors (i.e., `NEW` and `OLD`) in each group, then we could add `factor` as an additional grouping variable and use `slice` to only keep the first row of each group.

```
df2 <- structure(list(model = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A"
), country = c("Italy", "Germany", "Norway", "Italy", "France", 
"Germany", "Norway", "Italy"), year = c(2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2016), value = c(14, 34, 11, 34, 33, 11, 33, 
22), factor = c("NEW", "OLD", "OLD", "OLD", "OLD", "OLD", "NEW", 
"NEW")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

#  model country year value factor
#1     A   Italy 2016    14    NEW
#2     B Germany 2016    34    OLD
#3     C  Norway 2016    11    OLD
#4     A   Italy 2016    34    OLD
#5     A  France 2015    33    OLD
#6     C Germany 2015    11    OLD
#7     B  Norway 2015    33    NEW
#8     A   Italy 2016    22    NEW

df2 %>%
  group_by(model, country, year) %>%
  filter(n() > 1 & n_distinct(factor) > 1) %>%
  group_by(factor, .add = T) %>%
  slice(1)
```

*Output*

```
  model country  year value factor
  <chr> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1 A     Italy    2016    14 NEW   
2 A     Italy    2016    34 OLD
```